# Unable to connect to Mongo from pyspark

Tags: python, mongodb, pyspark

I'm trying to connect to MongoDB using pyspark. Below is the code I'm using

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sparkConf = SparkConf().setAppName("App")
sparkConf.set("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/mydb.test")
sc = SparkContext(conf = sparkConf)
sqlContext =SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").load()
df.printSchema()
```

I'm facing the below error

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o25.load.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Failed to find data source: com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource.

This error indicates that [PySpark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/) failed to locate [MongoDB Spark Connector](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/python-api/).

If you're invoking `pyspark` directly, make sure you specify `mongo-spark-connector` in the packages parameter. For example:

```
./bin/pyspark --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.2.0
```

If you're not invoking pyspark directly (i.e. from an IDE such as Eclipse) you would have to modify Spark configuration `spark.jars.packages` to specify the dependency.

Either within the `spark-defaults.conf` file:

```
spark.jars.packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.2.0
```

Or, you can try changing the configuration within the code:

```
SparkConf().set("spark.jars.packages","org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.2.0")
```

Or:

```
SparkSession.builder.config('spark.jars.packages','org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.2.0' ).getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. I could insert and find documents from pyspark shell but I could **not** using this code snippet within pyspark runtime:

```
SparkSession.builder.config('spark.jars.packages','org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.2.0' ).getOrCreate()
```

You Also may need to **add packages manually** to *$SPARK_HOME/jars*. Consider this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53997287/10059628).