# Failed to find data source: com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to connect spark (pyspark) to mongodb as follows:

```
conf = SparkConf()
conf.set('spark.mongodb.input.uri', default_mongo_uri)
conf.set('spark.mongodb.output.uri', default_mongo_uri)
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("my-app") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", default_mongo_uri) \
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", default_mongo_uri) \
    .getOrCreate()
```

But when I do the following:

```
users = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource") \
        .option("uri", '{uri}.{col}'.format(uri=mongo_uri, col='users')).load()
```

I get this error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source:
>   com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource

I did the same thing from pyspark shell and I was able to retrieve data. This is the command I ran:

```
pyspark --conf "spark.mongodb.input.uri=mongodb_uri" --conf "spark.mongodb.output.uri=mongodburi" --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.2.2
```

But here we have the option to specify the package we need to use. But what about standalone apps and scripts. how can I configure mongo-spark-connector there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

Here how I did it in Jupyter notebook:

 
1. Download jars from central or any other repository and put them in directory called "jars":

 mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.4.0

 mongo-java-driver-3.9.0

2. Create session and write/read any data

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

working_directory = 'jars/*'

my_spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("myApp") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.myCollection") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.myCollection") \
    .config('spark.driver.extraClassPath', working_directory) \
    .getOrCreate()

people = my_spark.createDataFrame([("JULIA", 50), ("Gandalf", 1000), ("Thorin", 195), ("Balin", 178), ("Kili", 77),
                            ("Dwalin", 169), ("Oin", 167), ("Gloin", 158), ("Fili", 82), ("Bombur", 22)], ["name", "age"])

people.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").mode("append").save()

df = my_spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").load()
df.select('*').where(col("name") == "JULIA").show()
```

As a result you will see this: 
[image]

Answer (score 8):

If you are using **SparkContext & SparkSession**, you have mentioned the connector jar packages in SparkConf, check the following Code:

```
    from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf
    conf = SparkConf().set("spark.jars.packages", "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.3.2")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("myApp") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017/sample1.zips") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017/sample1.zips") \
    .getOrCreate()

    df = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").load()
    df.printSchema()
```

If you are using **only SparkSession** then use following code:

```
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("myApp") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017/sample1.zips") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017/sample1.zips") \
    .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.3.2') \
    .getOrCreate()

    df = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").load()
    df.printSchema()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the newest version of mongo-spark-connector, i.e. v10.0.1 at the time of writing this, you need to use `SparkConf` object, as stated by the mongo documentation (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/spark-connector/current/configuration/).

Besides, you don't need to manually download anything, it will do it for you.

Bellow is the solution I came up with, for :

- mongo-spark-connector: 10.0.1
- mongo server : 5.0.8
- spark : 3.2.0

```
def init_spark():
    password = os.environ["MONGODB_PASSWORD"]
    user = os.environ["MONGODB_USER"]
    host = os.environ["MONGODB_HOST"]
    db_auth = os.environ["MONGODB_DB_AUTH"]
    mongo_conn = f"mongodb://{user}:{password}@{host}:27017/{db_auth}"

    conf = SparkConf()

    # Download mongo-spark-connector and its dependencies.
    # This will download all the necessary jars and put them in your $HOME/.ivy2/jars, no need to manually download them :
    conf.set("spark.jars.packages",
             "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector:10.0.1")

    # Set up read connection :
    conf.set("spark.mongodb.read.connection.uri", mongo_conn)
    conf.set("spark.mongodb.read.database", "<my-read-database>")
    conf.set("spark.mongodb.read.collection", "<my-read-collection>")

    # Set up write connection
    conf.set("spark.mongodb.write.connection.uri", mongo_conn)
    conf.set("spark.mongodb.write.database", "<my-write-database>")
    conf.set("spark.mongodb.write.collection", "<my-write-collection>")
    # If you need to update instead of inserting :
    conf.set("spark.mongodb.write.operationType", "update")

    SparkContext(conf=conf)

    return SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName('<my-app-name>') \
        .getOrCreate()

spark = init_spark()
df = spark.read.format("mongodb").load()

df_grouped = df.groupBy("<some-column>").agg(mean("<some-other-column>"))

df_grouped.write.format("mongodb").mode("append").save()
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing same error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource" while trying to connect to MongoDB from Spark (2.3).

I had to download and copy **mongo-spark-connector_2.11 JAR file(s)** into **jars** directory of spark installation.

That resolved my issue and I was successfully able to call my spark code via spark-submit.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This worked for me, but now I get an error `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bson.conversions.Bson` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how this error got resolved by downloading the jar files below. (Used the solution of this question.)

1.Downloaded the jar files below.

mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.4.1 from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb.spark/mongo-spark-connector_2.11/2.4.1)

mongo-java-driver-3.9.0 from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.9.0)

2. copy and paste both these jar files into 'jars' location in spark directory.
3. Pyspark Code in jupiter notebook:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("mongo").\
config("spark.mongodb.input.uri","mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/$database.$table_name").\
config("spark.mongodb.output.uri","mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/$database.$table_name").\
getOrCreate()

df=spark.read.format('com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource')\
    .option( "uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/$database.$table_name") \
    .load()

df.printSchema()

#create Temp view of df to view the data 
table = df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")

#to read table present in mongodb
query1 = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM df ")
query1.show(10)
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not using sc to create the SparkSession. Maybe this code can help you:

```
conf.set('spark.mongodb.input.uri', mongodb_input_uri)
conf.set('spark.mongodb.input.collection', 'collection_name')
conf.set('spark.mongodb.output.uri', mongodb_output_uri)
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc) # Using the context (conf) to create the session
```