# Saving a pyspark dataframe to mongodb gives an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

I try to save a pyspark dataframe to mongodb using a google cloud dataproc cluster, but it keeps showing me an error message.
I'm using spark `2.4.7` and python `3.7`, and mongoDB spark connector `2.4.3`
Here is my code:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder\
                    .master("yarn")\
                    .appName("demo")\
                    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri",
                             "mongodb+srv://my_host:27017/people_db") \
                    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri",
                            "mongodb+srv://my_host:27017/people_db") \
                    .config('spark.jars.packages',
                            'org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12-2.4.3')\
                    .getOrCreate()
df = spark.read\
          .format('csv')\
          .options(header=True)\
          .load(csv_path)

# ----------Some data processing -----------

df.write\    #This is the block of code that shows the error
  .format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")\
  .mode("append")\
  .option("collection", "people")\
  .save()
```

Here is the error message:

[image]

Comment: The error is saying the class `ConnectionString` cannot be found from your classpath. I don't believe Dataproc manages MongoDB related dependencies so a conflict is unlikely. Is the same Spark application running fine on a non-Dataproc cluster? What if you add the `mongo-java-driver` artifact from https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/mongodb/spark/mongo-spark-connector_2.12/2.4.3/mongo-spark-connector_2.12-2.4.3.pom as well to your Spark packages list?

Comment: Thank you so much @cyxxy for your help, I added the mongo java driver jar file to spark packages list and it works very well

Answer (score 0):

The mongo driver jar is not included in the class path. The two mongo jars (connector and driver) are essential in spark/jars path.
I was able to run on local and also as dataproc job by referring to the below link.
Mongo connector : 2.12_3.0.1
Mongo java driver : 3.12
Spark : 3.0.2

[Mongo dependencies required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50963444/failed-to-find-data-source-com-mongodb-spark-sql-defaultsource)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31015144)